# style parent element when hover on children element

Tags: drop-down-menu, parent-child, jquery-hover

I have a 2 levels dropdown-menu . 
on hover first level, the second is visible and I put a border-bottom on parent. But when I enter the second level, the border does not apply , I'd like it also applies when hover on children element.
Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did with jQuery

```
$x('.dropdown-menu')
.mouseenter(function(){
    $x(this).each(function() {
        $x(this).parent().css('border-bottom','1px solid #e36161');
    })
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $x(this).each(function() {
        $x(this).parent().css('border-bottom','none');
    })
});
```

it's ok